# Android Photo Scanning

Tags: android

I am looking to develop an application that will allow the user to launch the camera and use it to scan what the camera sees for a certain logo or word.

I have had some experience using the Zebra barcode scanning library so I am able to launch the camera and scan for a barcode fine.

The issue comes when I try to scan for a logo. Is it at all possible to scan for the logo in real time with the camera or would I have to have the user take picture and then scan the newly take picture and compare it with the logo that is being searched for?

Comment: How will the camera differntiate between logos ? This requires lots of data and image analysis algorithms

Comment: There are external SDKs that provide the functionality that you need. For example, take a look at Vuforia Image Targets or Cloud Recognition examples.

Answer (score 0):

Scanning for a logo is an entirely different problem. The Zebra Library has been designed specifically to recognized barcodes and qr codes anything outside of that scope and it won't be able to interpret anything. You can scan for logos in real time or on the cloud. Amazon does this with their shopping application so that you can research what you find at the supermarket or at a friends house.

There are companies that can offer you Image Recognition as a Service:
https://www.clarifai.com

or you can look into your own open source implementation
opencv.org/

There's examples for OpenCV for Android but you're going to need a bit of background on Machine Learning and Computer Vision before you get started.